# separator and split problems

Tags: algorithm, vbscript

I've been optimizing an application that was coded 10 years ago by other people. When I was analyzing problems, I encountered one which is very interesting. I have a bunch of string concatenated to each other using a separator ',' that will help us later split the strings, but one of the users actually put on a data field ',' , now the system is confused because it will consider that as a separator. And even if we change the separator, say for example put it '-' we can't know if some user will enter in a data field '-' as a data. Any solution for that ?

Comment: Please include some code so that we can visually see what the issue is. Also include sample data and desired input if nessecary

Comment: If this is for in-memory processing, don't concatenate values into a string, store each item independently within a data structure such as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doubling a character is a nice way to go. But there is always a chance that the string is the same thing as the separator

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem often seen in programming. To overcome it introduce an escape character. For instance `\` is often used for this purpose. Now of course you may need to enter `\` in your data. To get around this case, each occurrence of the real character `\` is doubled: i.e. you use `\\`.

Comment: I thought about this solution, but I said what if the user chooses to put '\\' as a data. We can't really predict what will be entered by the user

Comment: `\\` is replaced with `\\\\`, each `\` is replaced with `\` so the solution I describe works in all cases. Also this is a working solution used in many languages so it is proven to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a non printing ASCII code as the separator, such as RS or US ? They were made for such purposes.